# Why does a 'direction: rtl' cut off any numbers (but not letters) in a string and paste them at the end?

Tags: css, string

I'm confused as to why using a 'direction: rtl' CSS on a couple of filename strings produces the following results. So for instance:

```
123.pdf becomes pdf.123, but
123_test.pdf becomes test.pdf_123
123_test_456.pdf becomes test_456.pdf_123
```

[image]

I've found I can use a `bidi-override: plaintext`, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to handle this behaviour, or still why it does this in the first place.

Comment: you will probably find your answer here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#direction

Comment: Do you have a rule setting the `unicode-bidi` to either  `isolate` or `embed`?

Comment: Most of the direction rules defer ultimately to the [Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm](https://unicode.org/reports/tr9/). Which means that each character can have its own rules about how it interacts with the algorithm.